# How do I put measures in MDX query using Olap4j

Tags: olap, olap4j

[Olap4j documentation](http://olap4j-demo.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/Olap4j_Introduction_An_end_user_perspective.pdf) gives a good example of constructing simple MDX query:

```java
Query myQuery = new Query("SomeArbitraryName", salesCube);

QueryDimension productDim = myQuery.getDimension("Product");
QueryDimension storeDim = myQuery.getDimension("Store");
QueryDimension timeDim = myQuery.getDimension("Time");

myQuery.getAxis(Axis.COLUMNS).addDimension(productDim);
myQuery.getAxis(Axis.ROWS).addDimension(storeDim);
myQuery.getAxis(Axis.FILTER).addDimension(timeDim);
```

However, there is no info how to put `measure` into the query.

Is there a way to do this using Olap4j API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the point of view of MDX, there is a dimension called `Measures`, which has no hierarchies, but all the measures as its members. Thus, I would assume you can use this dimension like all the other dimensions and add it to the query.